# Bash: how to know if the last command's output ends with a newline or not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt

Most of the time the output of a command ends with the newline character. But sometimes it does not, so the next shell prompt is printed in the same line together with the output.

Example:

> root@hostname [~] # echo -n hello
>   helloroot@hostname [~] #

I've always found that very annoying.
Now, I could just add a "\n" at the beginning of the the PS1 variable, but most of the time that will print one extra line I dont need.

Is it possible to know whether the last command's output ended with a newline or not?

---

**Solution:**
(Thanks to Dennis)

```
PS1='$(printf "%$((`tput cols`-1))s\r")\u@\h [\w]\$ '
```

Comment: This should be moved to superuser.

Comment: I like your version! You used `$()` in one place and backticks in another. You can use `$()` in both.

Comment: I know. But for me it's easier to read that way

Comment: I wouldn't use `tput cols` because it just outputs the value of the COLUMNS variable anyway, and it's slower because it's not a shell builtin.  You'll also want to include `\e[K` (equivalent to `tput el`) to delete the inserted whitespace so that you don't get a bunch of trailing whitespace when copying and pasting in the default case.  Finally, you need to enclose all this magic between `\[` and `\]` or else bash will try to second-guess your cursor position and it'll mess up when you edit your command/history.

Comment: The whole thing can be done as just: `PS1='\[\e[7m%\e[m$( printf "%*s" "$((COLUMNS-1))" "" )\r\e[K\]\u@\h [\w]\$ '`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been experimenting with the following to emulate the feature from `zsh` in Bash:

```
$ unset PROMPT_SP; for ((i = 1; i <= $COLUMNS + 52; i++ )); do PROMPT_SP+=' '; done
$ PS1='\[\e[7m%\e[m\]${PROMPT_SP: -$COLUMNS+1}\015$ '
```

It issues a reverse video percent sign, followed by a bunch of spaces to make it wrap to the next line, then a carriage return, followed by a dollar sign and a space. You can add prompt escapes after the "\015" to customize your prompt.

Using this depends on how your terminal handles right margin line wrapping (automatic margins). The length of PROMPT_SP is arbitrary, but should be at least 80 or whatever your usual terminal width is. You may need to hard-code that value if $COLUMNS isn't set yet by the time the `for` loop is run in `~/.bashrc`. You may want `shopt -s checkwinsize` if it's not already set.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted *each answer*. Hmmm... no explanation. How helpful.

Comment: Here's another way, without using a loop, to create the pad string: `printf -v PROMPT_SP '%*s' $((COLUMNS + 52)) ''`

Comment: What is a "reverse video percent sign"? The word "video" has me confused, and I haven't been able to find the answer on Google.

Comment: @davidchambers: The background of the character is displayed in the foreground color and the character itself is displayed in the background color. See `man 5 terminfo` and search for "reverse video" to see some documentation that uses this terminology.

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` tries to solve your problem. If the last output ends without a newline, you will get:

```
$ echo -n 'abc'
abc%
$
```

Where the `%` uses inverted background/foreground. Not sure if it's portable to `bash` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible.  Bash itself does not process or see the output of the program it has started.

It just occured to me that it **might** be possible to write a program to set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to, which would check the current position of the cursor and issue a newline if the cursor was not at the left edge.

Comment: Good idea. The only problem is... is it possible to know the cursor position?

Answer (score 0):

I got this idea from @Teddy of detecting the horizontal cursor position and issuing a newline if it isn't at the first column.

In bash, we can detect the cursor position using this command: `IFS=';' read -sdR -p $'\E[6n' ROW COL`. More information in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183121/340297
The `COL` variable holds the current column where the cursor is. If `$COL` is not equal to 1, add a newline before setting the PS1 variable.

Here is my implementation:

```bash
_set_prompt() {
    IFS=';' read -sdR -p $'\E[6n' ROW COL # Get cursor position
    [ $COL -ne 1 ] && echo '' # Add newline if cursor is not at 1st column
    PS1="........." # Your PS1 variable
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'_set_prompt'
```

And here is the result (with different PS1):
[image]

`echo -n` doesn't include newline, but newline is issued before displaying the prompt. Whereas, there is no extra newline if newline is already printed by the normal echo command.